# Does const_cast ever cause actual code emission?

Tags: c++, constants, memory-model, const-cast, data-representation

Is it true that *const_cast* is just a way to tell the compiler "stop moaning, treat this as a non-const pointer"? Are there any cases when *const_cast* itself is translated into actual machine code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conceivably,there could be architectures where a const pointer had a different representation to a non-const one, in which case the compiler would have to emit some code. I'm not aware of any such architectures, however.

Comment: Clever, but not true: const is attribute only, it does not mean you cannot write (consider mutable members). If you are conceiving an architecture where read-only and read-write or write-only pointers are different, then the code still will not be generated on cast, rather on the write itself.

Comment: I intentionally didn't say _when_ the compiler would have to emit some code.

Comment: Doesn't matter at all. The const_cast woud remove the hypothetical "read-only bit" in the pointer, as would writes to a mutable member through a const pointer. The latter can be detected with 100% acuracy by the compiler.

Comment: Yeah, if anything, then would the conversion need to unset/set the bit. Writes to mutable members don't concern the pointer to the class-type anymore, since at that time, it's already de-referenced. Also note that what can be different at most are the bits that don't participate in the value calculation of the pointer. Those bits that do (value-representation) must be identical for T* and T const* (see 3.9.2/3).

Comment: "_there could be architectures where a const pointer had a different representation to a non-const one_" No.

Comment: @MSalters "_The const_cast woud remove the hypothetical "read-only bit" in the pointer_" This bit cannot exist, period.

Comment: @curiousguy: That statement is exactly what is questioned here. If you have proof, please add that as an answer.

Answer (score 12):

No, it just removes const attribute at compile time.

Answer (score 3):

const_cast just throws away the constness of an attribute and nothing more.

Answer (score 2):

`const` does not change the representation of a type, in particular, the representation of `T*` is exactly the same as `T const*`.

Consider:

```
int i, 
    * const cpi = &i,
    * const * pcpi = &cpi;
int const * const * pcpci = pcpi; // cpi is now int const*
```

The representation of `cpi` at the same time represents an `int*` and a `int const*` via `*pcpci`.

There is no way for the representation of `cpi` to change when `pcpci` is initialised.

Of course, if the pointer objects have non-significant bits, the compiler can flip them randomly; in particular, `const_cast` can flip the non-significant bits of a pointer, but any implicit conversion could also. I don't think this case exists in the real world.

The same apply when two different bit patterns result in the same address value (base+offset when offset is big enough).